# Android implementing realtime permission managment not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to implementing `PermissionsDispatcher` library on my project, but it doesn't work correctly for my project and don't ask permission, after read more the library source and implementing project like with that my doing work is not successful

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class ActivityContactLists extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_lists);

        ...

        long contact_count = realm.where(ContactLists.class).count();
        if (contact_count > 0 && !checkNetWorkConnection() && !connectingToServer) {
            reloadFromDatabase();
        } else {
            MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.showContactsWithCheck(this);
            syncByServer();
        }
    }

    private void reloadFromDatabase() {

    }

    /* MUST ASK PERMISSION REQUEST */
    @NeedsPermission({Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS})
    public void syncByServer() {
      /* READ CONTACTS FROM PHONE DATABASE */
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.syncronizeContacts)
    public void syncronizeContacts(View view) {
        syncByServer();
    }

    @OnShowRationale({Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS})
    void showRationaleForContact(PermissionRequest request) {
        showRationaleDialog(R.string.permission_contacts_rationale, request);
    }

    private void showRationaleDialog(@StringRes int messageResId, final PermissionRequest request) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        request.proceed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        request.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(messageResId)
                .show();
    }
}
```

And `MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher` class to handle Permission like with the library sampple code:

```
final class MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher {
    private static final int REQUEST_SHOWCONTACTS = 1;

    private static final String[] PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS = new String[]{
            "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS",
            "android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"
    };

    private MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher() {
    }

    static void showContactsWithCheck(ActivityContactLists target) {
        if (PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS)) {
            target.syncByServer();
        }
        if (PermissionUtils.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS)) {
            target.showRationaleForContact(new ShowContactsPermissionRequest(target));
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS, REQUEST_SHOWCONTACTS);
        }
    }

    static void onRequestPermissionsResult(ActivityContactLists target, int requestCode, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_SHOWCONTACTS:
                if (PermissionUtils.getTargetSdkVersion(target) < 23 && !PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (PermissionUtils.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {
                    target.syncByServer();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private static final class ShowContactsPermissionRequest implements PermissionRequest {
        private final WeakReference<ActivityContactLists> weakTarget;

        private ShowContactsPermissionRequest(ActivityContactLists target) {
            this.weakTarget = new WeakReference<>(target);
        }

        @Override
        public void proceed() {
            ActivityContactLists target = weakTarget.get();
            if (target == null) return;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(target, PERMISSION_SHOWCONTACTS, REQUEST_SHOWCONTACTS);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find whats problem which that don't ask permission

Comment: First Check, If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher.

Comment: @Raman yes sir, my android device version is 6.0.1 now, the library sample code work fine on my device but i cant implementing that